# Can i use the ne and eq in deployment.yaml like below?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates, helm3

I am trying to use ne and eq in **deployment.yaml** but while template helm getting below error

**Error**:YAML parse error on cdp/templates/cdp-deployment.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 50: did not find expected key

```
   {{- if (or (ne .Values.metadata.name "application-A") (eq .Values.metadata.name "application-B") )}}
                ports:
                - containerPort: {{ .Values.service.port }}
                envFrom:
                - configMapRef:
                    name: {{ .Values.metadata.name }}
                - secretRef:
                    name: {{ .Values.metadata.name }}
        {{- end }}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: How exactly are you deploying these resources? You've tagged this question with `helm`; can you update the question to show the layout of your repository and the deploy command you're using?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.  Helm is based on text or strings for that matter. So getting structure and indentation right can be difficult and is one of its shortcomings. Your error originates from something you don't show here. Your template does not produce valid yaml.

Comment: You can render the chart with `helm template ./path/to/my-chart/ --debug` and inspect the output. Alot of times you can find the problem this way.

Comment: Can you put this block in a little more context; what's before this `if` block?  The conditional seems correct and you're getting a YAML parse error, so it's not something with your use of `ne`.  (You also might consider writing a separate `templates/deployment-a.yaml` for each part, rather than trying to duplicate a Kubernetes-like values structure in your template code.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with this if statement. I tried to write a demo to test it. There is no problem with this paragraph.

values.yaml

```yaml
metadata:
  name: application-B
```

templates/cm.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  cfg: |-
    {{- if (or (ne .Values.metadata.name "application-A") (eq .Values.metadata.name "application-B") )}}
    ok
    {{- else }}
    notok
    {{- end }}
```

output

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-v32
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: test-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: test
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: test
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.16.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
data: 
  cfg: |-
    ok
```

The rendered line labels are not the same as the actual line labels, as the fool said, you should call the `helm template --debug test .` command to debug to see what the problem is.